# jsPlumb - Is it possible to assign endpoints to group of element using class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I would like to assign same endpoint to various container. But I have to manually assign them to each container like:

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint('window', { anchor:[0.5, 1, 0, 1] }, exampleEndpoint2);
jsPlumb.addEndpoint('window2', { anchor:"RightMiddle" }, exampleEndpoint2);
jsPlumb.addEndpoint("window3", { anchor:[0.75, 0, 0, -1] }, exampleEndpoint2);
jsPlumb.addEndpoint("window4", { anchor:[0.25, 0, 0, -1] }, exampleEndpoint2);
```

Is there a way I can assign this to a class selector like:

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint(".window", { anchor:[0.25, 0, 0, -1] }, exampleEndpoint2);
```

Or may be a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a jQuery selector like this:

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(".window"), { anchor:[0.25, 0, 0, -1] }, exampleEndpoint2);
```

Comment: Great, is there a way to delegate such bindings as well?

Comment: Do you mean to wait for an element to show up in the dom? At the time you make the jsPlumb call the element should be in the dom. Of course you can use jquery or other libraries that you are using to ensure that will happen. But as far as I understand, jsPlumb itself does not have a method to wait for dom elements.